# Composer - Add a specific folder of a git repository as dependency

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I know that you can use git repositories as a dependency with composer. However I am wondering if I can add a specific folder of a git repo as a dependency. For instance the Add Meta Tags Mod of Wordpress is in a shared repo:
https://github.com/svn2github/wordpress-vip-plugins/tree/master/add-meta-tags-mod

Can I set Composer to only download the `add-meta-tags-mod` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use source SVN - git does not support partial checkouts, so it may be hard to get this with git repo while it is quite easy with SVN:

```
{
    "require": {
        "wordpress-vip-plugin/add-meta-tags-mod": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "wordpress-vip-plugin/add-meta-tags-mod",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://vip-svn.wordpress.com/plugins/add-meta-tags-mod/",
                    "type": "svn",
                    "reference": "/"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This did work!! Thank you! However it installs inside the `vendor` folder. Can it be set up to install outside the vendor folder?

Comment: You may use https://packagist.org/packages/composer/installers for this.

Comment: I don't see that plugin in packagist.org unfortunately.

Comment: I mean that you may use `composer/installers` plugin to customize installation paths. There are examples in documentation.